# How to navigate from parent navigator to a screen in child navigator?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

Let's say I have this navigators structure

```
const Child = StackNavigator({
    Foo: { screen: FooScreen },
    Bar: { screen: BarScreen }
});

const Parent = StackNavigator({
    Main: { screen: Child },
    Baz: { screen: BazScreen }
});

export default Parent;
```

How can I access a screen in `Child`, from a screen in `Parent`?

I would like for instance, to navigate from `Baz` to `Bar`.

Following [react-community/react-navigation](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/blob/master/docs/guides/Screen-Navigation-Prop.md#navigate---link-to-other-screens), it states:

> If the screen is a navigator. See [Actions Doc](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/blob/master/docs/guides/navigation-actions) for a full list of supported actions.

But heyy link is dead !

So [How to Fix a 404 Not Found Error](https://www.lifewire.com/404-not-found-error-explained-2622936) does not sound right, so How can I access a screen in `Child`, from a screen in `Parent`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Baz

```
this.props.navigation.dispatch(
  NavigationActions.navigate({
    routeName: 'Main',
    action: NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Bar' }),
  }),
);
```

Comment: NavigationAction has been deprecated after React Navigation 4.x and replaced by CommonActions, but CommonActions don't have ```action``` property in it. Can you please explain how to do the same in React Navigation 5.x

Answer (score 2):

The default behavior of React Navigation v5.x is

> Navigation actions are handled by current navigator and bubble up if
> couldn't be handled

However based on their docs,

> If you need to dispatch actions to the nested child navigators from a parent, you can use navigation.dispatch

Now from parent navigator (Baz) with access to navigation props

```
import { CommonActions } from '@react-navigation/native';

// navigation came from parent props
navigation.dispatch(CommonActions.navigate({ name: 'Bar'}));
```

Here are the links for reference,

[Navigation actions are handled by current navigator and bubble up if couldn't be handled](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/#navigation-actions-are-handled-by-current-navigator-and-bubble-up-if-couldnt-be-handled)

[Navigator specific methods are available in the navigators nested inside](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/#navigator-specific-methods-are-available-in-the-navigators-nested-inside)

[Advanced API Reference - Dispatch](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop#advanced-api-reference)

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate(this.props.navigation.state.routes[1].routeName)
```

The [1] is the position of the tab in the Array or Screens, and the routeName should be Bar.

Answer (score 0):

If you just can't find any solution (as in my case), just do:

In your nested file:

`<StackNavigator ref={(x) => (global.childNavigator = x)} />`

In your parent:

```
global.childNavigator.dispatch(
   NavigationActions.navigate({
       routeName: 'Player',
       params: { },
   }),
);
```